# how to calculate dilution factor and CFU

Tags: bacteriology

I'm very confused 
I did a bacterial experiment where i added 5 grams to 70ml of distilled water that contains 10g of fresh meat. I left it in a sampler container over 24 hours then i cultured bacteria from the broth using an incubating loop onto nutrient agar. I left them to culture then observed 29 colonies of bacteria. 
I observed 1 bacterial colony under a light microscope and counted 19 bacterias. 
How do i calculate the dilution factor and CFU?
i need to calculate how many bacterias were on the agar plate? 
please help!

Comment: Do you know what CFU stands for?

Comment: What are your workings out so far? Did you record what magnification you viewed the colonies under? ( Eg. 200x ). Did you use a hemocytometer?   If you did, Google hemocytometer and lots of info will come up about finding the number of CFU including the formula/s required.